# BizTalk ListApp command line

Tags: biztalk

I used the following code in c# to get policies\rules from deployed application in BizTalk server.

```
BTSTask.exe ListApp -ApplicationName:"EAISolution" -ResourceSpec:"c:\EAISolution.PolicyInf
o.xml" /Server:VHYDTRBELSUP-02 /Database:BizTalkMgmtDb
```

From above command I got the output as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16" ?> 
<ResourceSpec xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"                              xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" ApplicationName="EAISolution" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/ApplicationDeployment/ResourceSpec/2004/12">
<Resources>
<Resource Type="System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly" Luid="EAIOrchestration, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=97e0f507fd7fd10d" /> 
<Resource Type="System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly" Luid="EAIServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=97e0f507fd7fd10d" /> 
<Resource Type="System.BizTalk:BizTalkAssembly" Luid="FFSchemasTest, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=97e0f507fd7fd10d" /> 
<Resource Type="System.BizTalk:Rules" Luid="RULE/ProcessPurchaseOrder/1.0" /> 
<Resource Type="System.BizTalk:BizTalkBinding" Luid="Application/EAISolution" /> 
</Resources>
</ResourceSpec>
```

and from BizTalk server I got the below output using policy export in BizTalk server administration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<brl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/businessruleslanguage/2002">
<ruleset name="ProcessPurchaseOrder">
<version major="1" minor="0" description="" modifiedby="username" date="2013-05- 27T12:04:55.6121122+05:30" /> 
<configuration /> 
<bindings>
<xmldocument ref="xml_31" doctype="RuleTest.PO" instances="16" selectivity="1" instance="0">
<selector>/*[local-name()='PurchaseOrder' and namespace-uri() ='http://EAISolution.PurchaseOrder']/*[local-name()='Item' and namespace-uri()='']</selector> 
<selectoralias>/PurchaseOrder/Item</selectoralias> 
<schema>....\PO.xsd</schema> 
</xmldocument>
<xmldocument ref="xml_32" doctype="RuleTest.PO" instances="16" selectivity="1" instance="0">
<selector>/*[local-name()='PurchaseOrder' and namespace-uri()='http://EAISolution.PurchaseOrder']    
</selector> 
<selectoralias>/PurchaseOrder</selectoralias> 
<schema>....\PO.xsd</schema> 
</xmldocument>
</bindings>
<rule name="ApprovalRule" priority="0" active="true">
<if>
<compare operator="less than or equal to">
<vocabularylink uri="3f0e9bcc-6212-4e6a-853c-e517f157a626" element="d4eb2deb-06d3-42c4-af49-ceb21331b1cc" /> 
<lhs>
<function>
<xmldocumentmember xmldocumentref="xml_31" type="int" sideeffects="false">
<field>*[local-name()='Quantity' and namespace-uri()='']</field> 
<fieldalias>Quantity</fieldalias> 
</xmldocumentmember>
</function>
</lhs>
<rhs>
<constant>
<int>500</int> 
</constant>
</rhs>
</compare>
</if>
<then>
<function>
<xmldocumentmember xmldocumentref="xml_32" type="string" sideeffects="true">
<field>*[local-name()='Status' and namespace-uri()='']</field> 
<fieldalias>Status</fieldalias> 
<argument>
<constant>
<string>Approved</string> 
</constant>
</argument>
</xmldocumentmember>
</function>
</then>
</rule>
</ruleset>
</brl>
```

So please let me know how to get the output of second using command line.

Answer (score 0):

BTSTask will only export the policy as part of an MSI (see below). 
You could then extract the MSI (see [How to extract msu/msp/msi fileds from the command line](http://www.windowswiki.info/2009/02/19/how-to-extract-msumspmsiexe-files-from-the-command-line/)) to get the policy file.

From **[How to Import a Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa577374.aspx)**

> - BTSTask does not provide a specific command for importing *(or exporting)* policies; however you can use the ExportApp command of BTSTask to selectively export only the policies in an application that you want, including no other application artifacts. Then you can use the ImportApp command to import the .msi file into an application in a different BizTalk group. This is the approach described in this topic. When you do this, the policy is automatically imported and published in the BizTalk group and added to the specified application.

The below steps will get export the policy, but as part of an MSI.

From **[How to Export a Policy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa559417.aspx)**

> - Use the BTSTask ListApp command with the /ResourceSpec option to generate an XML file that lists the artifacts in the BizTalk application from which you want to export a policy, as described in ListApp Command.
>     *Edit the XML file generated in the previous step, deleting all of the artifacts except for the policy or policies that you want to export.*
>     Use the BTSTask ExportApp command, and specify the modified XML file for the /ResourceSpec parameter. For more information, see ExportApp Command.
>     BTSTask exports the specified policies and all of their associated vocabularies into an application .msi file.